# On WordPress metabox How to Keep the checked radio button checked after updating post

Tags: php, wordpress, radio-button, save, meta-boxes

I created a metabox that can be used to add a sidebar to a post. The get_sidebar function will be added to the post template using an if statement based on whether the user checks the sidebar radio button or not, but I haven't got that far yet.

So far the metabox shows up in the editor screen but when I check the sidebar radio button it returns unchecked after I update the post.

This is what I am using to keep the radio button checked after the post has been updated.

```
$layout = $_POST["layout"]; 
<input type="radio" name="layout" <?php if (isset($layout) && $layout=="right-sidebar") echo "checked"; ?> value="right-sidebar">
```

This is the full code I am using to create and update the metabox:

```
<?php

function hill_add_layout_metabox() {

    add_meta_box(
        'layout_metabox',
        'Layout1',
        'hill_callback_layout_matabox',
        'post',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'hill_add_layout_metabox');

function hill_callback_layout_matabox() {
    $layout = $_POST["layout"]; 
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" <?php if (isset($layout) && $layout=="right-sidebar") echo "checked"; ?> value="right-sidebar">  Right Sidebar

    <?php
}

function hill_save_layout_metabox($post_id) {
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave ( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision ( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    $layout = $_POST["layout"];

    if (isset($layout) && $layout=="right-sidebar") {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $layout );
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'hill_save_layout_metabox');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to add custom meta box in post . Refer the below links it will solved your problem .

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for gathering up those links for me but I have read all three articles prior to using this site

Answer (score 0):

First, when saving the meta value, add a value to be saved:

It's a matter of preference, but I'll set the value to 'on' if checked other wise ''.

```
$value = isset($layout) && $layout=='right-sidebar' ? 'on' : ''
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'right-sidebar', $value  );
```

After updating the post, get the value you saved using get_post_meta and set the radio button if needed; the WP [`checked()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) function is handy for this:

```
<?php $check = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'right-sidebar', true ); ?>
<input type="radio" name="layout" <?php checked( $check, 'on' ); ?> value="right-sidebar">
```

Comment: Thanks @Billk I tried doing what you suggested and nothing changed. Maybe I misunderstood something. Is There suppose to be a semicolon on the first line of code you shared on the first block

Comment: The semicolon is part of the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), a shorthand for if:else. If `$layout` meets the conditions store 'on' in the meta table else (:) store an empty string.  It looks like your original code is not getting the meta button value from the database, have you used phpMyAdmin to look in your database?